# Change Sharepoint Search Flow Config

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I'm trying to update the sharepoint search flow configuration to change the weight of synomyms (from 0.2 to 1) by exporting the flow configuration with the following commands:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Search\Scripts\ceresshell.ps1"
Connect-System -Uri  (Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication).SystemManagerLocations[0] -ServiceIdentity (Get-SPEnterpriseSearchService).ProcessIdentity
Connect-Engine -NodeTypes InterActionEngine

$flowname = Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow
Get-Flow $flowname  > $flowname.txt
```

The last command leads to the following error:

```
Get-Flow : Cannot access a disposed object. 
Object name: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel'. 
At E:\installsw\Export Search FLow.ps1:13 char:1 
+ Get-Flow Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow > $flowPathName 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Flow], ObjectDisposedException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ObjectDisposedException,Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Cmdlets.GetFlow
```

Can anyone help me with this error?